# How can I encrypt the same message on different machines?

Tags: python, pycrypto

I'm working with some sensitive data and need to encrypt identification numbers (9 digits).

In the future, I may have to get more data from where it is currently stored and add it to a database.  I want the encryption to be so such that if I add an existing subject to the database, all the plain text of the encrypted identification numbers are the same.

For instance, if I wanted to encrypt `123456789`, then the resulting plain text of the encrypted data should be the same no matter which machine I use to encrypt the data.  Likewise, if any of my collaborators have to implement similar encryption in a different language (say Java for instance), their future encrypted plain text should match encrypted plain text from the past.

I know AES in ECB mode is a deterministic encryption scheme and perhaps may not be best for long messages, but since these are so short, and I need total control of the encryption, I thought it may be appropriate.

How can I implement something like I have described using pycrypto?  Is ECB mode the appropriate mode?

Comment: If you use ECB mode, or even CBC with a static IV, encryption of two identical messages will result in the same encrypted data potential;ly leaking information. You really need to use CBC mode with a random IV, just prepend the IV to the encrypted data for used during decryption.

Comment: Do you really need to encrypt the numbers? Or could you just hash them? That is, do you need to be able to get the number back ('123456789') or is it sufficient to just be able to ask "My id number is 123456789, do I have HIV?" and do a lookup like `SELECT has_hiv FROM info WHERE hashed_id = hash('123456789')` ?

Comment: @AustinHastings Yes, we may need to be able to get the number back in the future.

Comment: @zaph I understand the weakness in static IV, and if it were up to me I would use a random IV.  However, if I use a static IV for CBC, would I accomplish what I need?

Comment: @DemetriP Yes, you could, but the question remains, why? You can probably redesign your system slightly so that it is not necessary to use deterministic encryption.

Comment: @ArtjomB. These instructions aren't really up to me, but I agree.  Could you recommend something?  I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I don't exactly know your architecture and other constraints, so I can't recommend anything. Also, such a detailed question about a redesign would be better suited for [security.se] or [crypto.se].